# End titles and subtitles with a period

Tags: python, regex

How do I mark the end of a subtitle such that during sentence split, it is treated as a separate sentence?

Input text:

```
The Cat\n
Now is the time for the quick\n
brown cat to jump over.
```

Output text:

```
The Cat.
Now is the time for the quick\n
brown cat to jump over.
```

Subtitles don’t have ending punctuation, but are usually followed by the uppercase letter start of the following sentence.
I’ve tried the following regex, and variations, but no cigar. (A substring with a `\n` followed by a capital letter is replaced by the period mark followed and the capital letter.)

```
print(re.sub[r'\n([A-Z])',r"\.\1",text])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

`(?<!\.)([\r\n]+)\s*([A-Z])`

```
(?<!         // Negative lookbehind (nothing to correct if period already exists)
    \.       // Period
)            // Close negative lookbehind
(            // Open capture group
    [\r\n]+  // Newline (can be \r\n, \r, or \n)
)            // Close capture group
\s*          // Any amount of whitespace
(            // Open Capture group
    [A-Z]    // Capital letter
)            // Close capture group
```

Replace with: `.\1\2`

[Test Here](https://regex101.com/r/iaNGpW/1)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I used the suggested code as follows:

 long_line = re.sub(r"(?<!\.)([\r\n]+)\s*([A-Z])",'.\1\2',long_line)

The input: 
Ang Biktima     (<— There’s a new line symbol at end of line.)
Nagsimula ang lahat sa mga bangus ni Sonia.

The output:
Ang Biktima Nagsimula ang lahat sa mga bangus ni Sonia.

Looks like group 1 substitution doesn’t go through?

Comment: @user3607862 Like this? https://regex101.com/r/UZ7mlI/1